# Rearranged Subcategory Does not Reflect Store View

Tags: category

So this is bugging me for months now, and I have yet found any real solution. 
(Forgive me if this is already posted)

In the backend where you can manage category, it gives you an option to rearrange the subcategory by simply drag-and-drop then save. Which I did. But when I try to view the store view did not change to reflect the backend.

Sample image below:
[image: Sample image here]

The "Biological" page is suppose to be between the "Stereo" and the "Educational". But instead is at the very end.

Please help! I've tried refreshing the cache/index management but nothing is working...

Comment: First thing to try is rebuild your indexes and then clear the cache. Also, Magento does not offer by default a listing of categories. So I guess this is a custom code. You might want to post the code that retrieves the categories. It will help us identify the problem, if there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend checking your `catalog_category_entity` table. Sometimes the "position" of your categories gets changed where you  may have two categories with the same value for position (ie Position = 27) This may cause behavior such as this.

Your category's id in magento admin is = to entity_id in this table.

Also the way to identify if this is indeed the cause, is to look at the "level" value and the "parent_id" value

So you would find the id for "Products" category in your screenshot, this will be the parent_id

Then your level will be "3" since this is the 3rd level of your tree (Default > Products > Biological)

Now that you have filtered for parent_id and level , you will see if your categories in this level are conflicting by having identical positions.

SEPARATELY:

If it is not the above, did you also "Flush Cache Storage" and not just refresh? Have you tried on an incognito window in a new browser etc?

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to see how and what to change in the SQL but I wasn't sure which value it was. But I got it! I was hoping to be something simple but this works perfectly!

Comment: Thank you , I am very pleased this solved your problem, as it is an obscure thing that happens rarely, but can be maddening to fix! Your question unlocked the knowledge of it that I had stored in the brain but long forgotten. Cheers!

Comment: @Annie, What you did to solve this? I stuck with same problem

Comment: @Charlie The answer above works

Comment: @Charlie sorry this is late, but I think because I have godaddy linux as a sever, there's some feature that don't work like it suppose to. The SQL is one solution but the easiest think for me is to basically add and delete subfolders in order of how you want it to be displayed in the frontend. (I hope that makes sense). its tedious but it works.