# duplicate position entries in catalog_category_entity - can I edit the table directly?

Tags: category, database

I was looking at the answer given on [Rearranged Subcategory Does not Reflect Store View](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40926/rearranged-subcategory-does-not-reflect-store-view) but can't comment on it because I have low rep

My question is, am I safe to edit the position values in the `catalog_category_entity` table to fix duplicate entries? If not, is there a safer way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than editing table , create a **custom category attribute** as **position** and sort the collection according to it

**It is never safe to edit tables in Mangento DB directly**

Comment: I take your point about the safety of editing db tables directly but creating a custom category attribute seems a bit of overkill. This problem only affects one subcategory and seems to have arisen when dragging subcategories about in the parent category. However - since my question was about the safety of editing the db I feel I have to mark your answer - your method is indeed safer :)